# Ошибка при вынесении скрипта в отдельный js файл

Tags: jquery, javascript

Ребят, не могу понять почему код js написанный в месте с jQuery при вынесении в отдельный файл выдает ошибку в самом `jquery.js`?! Если его поместить на самой странице то все в порядке. Может я его как-то не так оформляю? Вот код:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//здесь мой код
});
```

вот ошибка:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

ссылаясь на сточки `jquery.js` 620-624:

```
var value,
        i = 0,
        length = obj.length,
        isArray = isArraylike( obj );
```

В чем проблема?!

[код на jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/igolka97/BvCmk/)

Comment: Выложите, пожалуйста, текст проблемного кода на ресурс типа `jsfiddle`

Comment: Вам же ясно говорится, что объект 'obj' is undefined, т.е. не определен, а так как он не определен, то у него не может быть свойства 'length'. Crasher прав, необходимо видеть весь код.

Comment: @Crasher @Mihey добавил ссылку в вопрос

Comment: @igolka97, ну и зачем выкладывать код с заведомо существующей проблемой? Переменной `url` не существует

Comment: видимо, data.data undefined

 вообще, проще всего отловить такую ошибку выставив "pause on exeptions" или нечто подобное в dev tools/firebug и посмотрев callStack

Comment: @Crasher @eicto переменная `url` существует, а тосчнее в место url была ссылка на файл и я ее заменил что бы вы не видели на какой файл))
а ошибку отловленную с помощью `pause in exeptions` я вам уже дал  
и данные то приходят ели все в одном файле а когда ее выносишь в `.JS` то ничего не работает что делать?

Comment: не ошибка нужна а callstack, в смысле что с какими параметрами вызывается... (может $(function(){...}) забыли ?

Comment: Поддерживаю eicto

Answer (score 0):

Беда может быть в том, что браузеры не особо ладят с модульной системой. Если Вы разделили код по файлам, то все их необходимо подключить в HTML, никакие require и импорт тут не помогают.

Решения могут быть следующими:

- Писать одним файлом, если итоговый код небольшой;
- Подключать каждый файл в HTML и конечно же помнить о глобальных переменных;
- Настроить систему сборки Webpack, Gulp или другую.